# this.getDataValue is not a function - model sequelize v.5

Tags: sequelize.js

I cannot access this.getDataValue in sequelize model, but it says in documentation we can access it, I'm using SEQUELIZE v5. 
I dont know what I have to do, but I've been figuring out a lot of things.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    password : DataTypes.STRING,
    is_active : DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  }, {});

  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };

  User.toJSON = function () {
    var values = Object.assign({}, this.get());
    delete values.password;
    return values;
  }

  User.comparePassword = async function (email, pw) {
    let err, pass;
    //ERROR RIGHT HERE
    if(!this.getDataValue('password')) TE('password not set');

    [err, pass] = await to(bcrypt_p.compare(pw, this.password));
    if(err) TE(err);

    if(!pass) TE('invalid password');

    return this;
  }

  User.getJWT = function () {
    return "Bearer "+jwt.sign({id:this.id}, "BAMBANG", {expiresIn: 86400});
  };

  User.toWeb = function () {
    let json = this.toJSON();
    return json;
  };

  return User;
};
```

Comment: Did you check 'this' at the error line? Is it a static model object or a record instance?

Comment: yes, i check it, it returns User instance, I've tried it also, but not working

Comment: docs says you can call getDataVelue in getters and setters defined in a model.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have added class methods instead of an instance methods. This is an example from the official docs:

```
// Adding a class level method
User.classLevelMethod = function() {
  return 'foo';
};

// Adding an instance level method
User.prototype.instanceLevelMethod = function() {
  return 'bar';
};
```

Comment: i think its v4, im using v5

Comment: in v5 models are defined as es6 classes. I don't such definitions in your question